# Shared attribute accros models Enumerize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm using Enumerize gem and I would like to create an Enum that is shared among two models.

My model with Enum looks like this:

```
class StudyTypeEnum < ApplicationRecord

  extends Enumerize
  enumerize :studytype, in: {:full_time, :part_time}

end
```

and then I just include it in the other models

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord

  include StudyTypeEnum
  ...
```

Im not sure how to create the migration now, do I need to create the StudyType columns in both StudyTypeEnum and Course models?

Answer (score 1):

I would user concern for that kind of behavior.

in the file: `app/models/concerns/enumerable_study.rb`

```
module EnumerableStudy
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  extends Enumerize

  included do
    enumerize :studytype, in: {:full_time, :part_time}
  end
end
```

and then if any of your models need that field just do:

e.g in the file: `app/models/course`

```ruby
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  include EnumerableStudy
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby classes cannot be included in other classes - only modules can. Classes can only be used for "classical" vertical inheritance (a class inherits from a single base class).

```
module StudyTypeEnum
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend Enumerize
    base.class_eval do
      enumerize :studytype, in: {:full_time, :part_time}
    end
  end
end
```

Since the code needs to be executed in the context of the class that includes the module we need define a `self.included` method that is called when we include the class. You can also use [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) which wraps this common Ruby idiom.

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  include StudyTypeEnum
end
```

> Im not sure how to create the migration now, do I need to create the
>   StudyType columns in both StudyTypeEnum and Course models?

Since StudyTypeEnum is a module that is mixed into model classes it does have a table.

You only need to add the column to the actual models - in this case Course - and any other model that you plan on including StudyTypeEnum in.

Comment: I'm not sure if I would use the `Enumerize` gem though. It stores the enums as strings instead of simple integers like [ActiveRecord::Enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) which are faster to index and compare. I would say that the gem author kind of missed the whole point.